# Streaming query results closes prematurely - Spring Data JPA and Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, java-stream

**Here is a repository with the code in this question exibiting the bug:
https://github.com/agsimeonov/stream-bug**

I have been attempting to stream query results with Spring Data JPA and Hibernate using the following piece of code (data.txt is a file with 3000 lines with a number on each line):

```
try (Stream<Customer> stream = repository.streamAll()) {
  stream.forEach(customer -> {
    try {
      File data = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("data.txt").getFile());
      try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(data))) {
        while (reader.readLine() != null) {
          // Do stuff for the current customer
        }
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {}
    System.out.println(customer);
  });
}
```

Here is the domain object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;

  public Customer() {}

  public Customer(String firstName, String lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return String.format("Customer[id=%d, firstName='%s', lastName='%s']", id, firstName, lastName);
  }
}
```

And here is the repository:

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {
  @Query("SELECT c FROM Customer c")
  Stream<Customer> streamAll();
}
```

Doing this result in the following error:

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not advance using next()
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ScrollableResultsImpl.convert(ScrollableResultsImpl.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ScrollableResultsImpl.next(ScrollableResultsImpl.java:104)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.provider.PersistenceProvider$HibernateScrollableResultsIterator.hasNext(PersistenceProvider.java:454)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:115)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
    at stream.bug.StreamBugApplication.lambda$0(StreamBugApplication.java:34)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:800)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:784)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:771)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175)
    at stream.bug.StreamBugApplication.main(StreamBugApplication.java:22)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: The object is already closed [90007-193]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:144)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcResultSet.checkClosed(JdbcResultSet.java:3202)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcResultSet.next(JdbcResultSet.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ScrollableResultsImpl.next(ScrollableResultsImpl.java:99)
    ... 12 more
```

I have spent a lot of time debugging this and I have finally managed to create a small spring-boot example application exhibiting the streaming bug:
https://github.com/agsimeonov/stream-bug

**I know a few things for sure:**

**First** - This bug has nothing to do with the underlying database. 
While I am using H2 in the example project I have tried with
Postgres and the bug still occurs with a very similar error, note I
use tomcat connection pooling in my other project, I have tried
different connection pools so it is definitely not the connection
pool or the underlying database causing this.  Here is an example trace with postgres and tomcat connection pooling as you may notice it is very similar:

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not advance using next()
  at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
  at org.hibernate.internal.ScrollableResultsImpl.convert(ScrollableResultsImpl.java:69)
  at org.hibernate.internal.ScrollableResultsImpl.next(ScrollableResultsImpl.java:104)
  at org.springframework.data.jpa.provider.PersistenceProvider$HibernateScrollableResultsIterator.hasNext(PersistenceProvider.java:454)
  at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:115)
  at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
  at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
  at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
  at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
  at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
  at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
  at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
  at com.trove.sunstone.attributefusion.services.impl.PhysicalServiceImpl.match(PhysicalServiceImpl.java:130)
  at com.trove.sunstone.attributefusion.AppRunner.main(AppRunner.java:31)
  Suppressed: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy238.hashCode(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:338)
    at java.util.HashMap.get(HashMap.java:556)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl.release(ResourceRegistryStandardImpl.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractScrollableResults.close(AbstractScrollableResults.java:104)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.provider.PersistenceProvider$HibernateScrollableResultsIterator.close(PersistenceProvider.java:465)
    at org.springframework.data.util.StreamUtils$CloseableIteratorDisposingRunnable.run(StreamUtils.java:96)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.close(AbstractPipeline.java:323)
    at com.trove.sunstone.attributefusion.services.impl.PhysicalServiceImpl.match(PhysicalServiceImpl.java:137)
    ... 1 more
  Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Statement closed.
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractQueryReport$StatementProxy.invoke(AbstractQueryReport.java:224)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This ResultSet is closed.
  at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.checkClosed(PgResultSet.java:2740)
  at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.next(PgResultSet.java:1817)
  at org.hibernate.internal.ScrollableResultsImpl.next(ScrollableResultsImpl.java:99)
  ... 11 more
```

**Second** - the odd part is that removing the following lines from the forEach() in the stream results in the stream finishing properly. This leads me to believe it may be some sort of timing issue, however I have attempted to replicate it with Thread.sleep() instead of file reading with no success.  As a side note data.txt is a file with 3000 lines with a number on each line.

```
try {
  File data = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("data.txt").getFile());
  try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(data))) {
    while (reader.readLine() != null) {
      // Do stuff for the current customer
    }
  }
} catch (IOException e) {}
```

**Third** - Replacing:

```
Stream<Customer> stream = repository.streamAll()
```

With:

```
Stream<Customer> stream = repository.findAll().stream()
```

Fixes the issue so this is definitely a bug with streaming and/or ScrollableResults as loading all the data into a list makes the application finish with no errors, however for my current project I need to use Streams directly so using findAll() is not an option.

If someone has encountered this issue and been able to fix it please let me know.  Also please feel free to check out, fork, and/or change code in the provided repository which can help resolve this issue.  I have created this project as a demo that should be used to illustrate the bug.

Comment: A few unrelated notes: using File IO for a resource loaded with the class loader is wrong: as soon as the app is packaged in a jar or war, there won't be any file anymore. Just read from the stream returned by getResourceAsStream() directly. And reading the same 3000 lines from the resource for each element of your result set is a waste. Just read the lines once and for all, and store them in a List, Map or any best-suited  in-memory collection.

Comment: I realize this.  That piece of code is there just as an example of the issue.  In fact there are many different files and the one that gets read depends on the current customer so that is not something I can store in memory.  In this project I provide only 1 strictly as an example.  I packaged the file with the project and used the class loader for simplicity in my original project the input files are not packaged with the project.

Comment: Even for an example, there is no reason to use such broken code. The correct code is even shorter… It’s also unclear why you use try-with-resource with the stream, but not with the reader.

Comment: With “removing the following lines from the forEach()” you mean “removing all lines from forEach()”?

Comment: @Holger "It’s also unclear why you use try-with-resource with the stream"
It should be quite clear if you read the Spring Data JPA documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-streaming


As per the docs:
"A Stream potentially wraps underlying data store specific resources and must therefore be closed after usage. You can either manually close the Stream using the close() method or by using a Java 7 try-with-resources block."

Comment: @Holger as for possible improvements in the code and shortening it I understand quite well that it is possible but that is really quite besides the point.  I simply aim to illustrate that I would like to use BufferedReader.readLine() inside a stream forEach() and it doesn't work, as I stated this is simply demo code and it is syntactically correct however ugly and inefficient, and it should work, as it does when I change the streamAll() to findAll().stream().

Comment: @Holger by removing the following lines from the forEach() I mean the lines I mean everything besides the System.out.println(customer);  I should mention if you just remove the while (reader.readLine() != null) {} the stream would finish correctly as well.  I will edit the question to show this.

Comment: Don’t tear sentences apart when citing. I know very well that the stream has to be closed. What is unclear is why you display the knowledge at one place, but inconsistently don’t use it right afterwards. I see no reason why examples have to be written without care, using discouraged or even broken techniques, when writing a correct example is even simpler.

Comment: It’s not even possible to preclude that these broken things are *responsible* for the problems. You have a `catch(IOException ex){}` that will silently ignore exceptions und due to the manual closing, the reader will not be closed in the exceptional case, so you wouldn’t notice follow-up errors, like too many open file handles, either. So it would be *really* helpful to write a clean example that is sufficient t prove that this is not the case.

Comment: @Holger I seem to have a limit amount of characters available for comments as I don't often post on this site, so please excuse the fact that I may have to write multiple comments to answer questions. I apologize for misunderstanding your question.  I will change it over to consistent try-with.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I posted my question on the Spring Data JPA JIRA as a bug report and the issue was apparently observed before. After some discussion on there I now use @Transactional on the Stream related code to resolve the issue as a workaround.  Thanks goes to Oliver Gierke for pointing this out here:
https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-989?focusedCommentId=133710&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-133710

I have pushed the solution to the bug in the latest commit to my sample bug repository here:
https://github.com/agsimeonov/stream-bug/commit/9da536d0a9d921787f6d2d4d75720d363ba0358b

Comment: I ran into the same issue, thank you all for the question & answer.

Comment: In my situation the stream is exposed via a REST endpoint, thus that was the place @Transactional had to be added. But this does not seem to solve the problem if you use Jersey for the REST endpoints! Switching to Spring MVC solved it (with using @Transactional).